# Why is this code returning an empty CSV file instead of returning a CSV file with all rows matching the condition?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a file "MyFile.csv" whose 46th column contains some article IDs. I have an array `articleList` with a few article IDs that I want to match with MyFile.csv. I want to find all such rows in MyFile.csv which contains any of the articles in the `articleList` array, and save them in a new file "Articles.csv".

This is my code:

```
require 'csv'
require 'rubygems'

articleList = [600502,600574,600588,600740,600741,601190,601241,601342,601734,601887]

CSV.open('Articles.csv', "wb") do |csv|
    CSV.foreach('MyFile.csv') do |row|
        if !(row & articleList).empty?
            csv<<row
        end
    end
end
```

The "Articles.csv" file is always empty. I removed the `!` from the line `if !(row & articleList).empty?`, and the whole MyFile.csv file gets saved in Articles.csv, but when I eyeball the MyFile.csv data, I can see the rows which contain some of those articles in `articleList`. What's wrong with the code?

This is what a row in `MyFile.csv` looks like:

```
"{""timestamp"": ""2015-05-31 14:56:49"", ""article_category_id"": ""92"", ""app_name"": ""Apple Daily TW"", ""ip"": ""192.168.0.11"", ""app_id"": ""51ee0d904055aa1539d32523"", ""datetime"": ""1433084209738"", ""edition"": """", ""action"": ""page_view"", ""article_title"": ""å°?ç¬ åŽŸç¾¤å³¶å¤–æµ·8.5åœ°éœ‡ã€€ç‚ºä½•æ²’å¼•ç™¼æµ·å˜¯ï¼Ÿ"", ""user_id"": """", ""menu"": ""å?³æ™‚æ–°è?ž"", ""lon"": """", ""platform"": ""Android"", ""country_residence"": """", ""version"": ""2.6.0"", ""page_name"": ""å°?ç¬ åŽŸç¾¤å³¶å¤–æµ·8.5åœ°éœ‡ã€€ç‚ºä½•æ²’å¼•ç™¼æµ·å˜¯ï¼Ÿ"", ""location"": """", ""is_registered"": ""False"", ""provider"": """", ""page_id"": ""620259"", ""menu_id"": ""10002"",  ""article_category"": ""æœ€æ–°"", ""lat"": """", ""article_id"": ""620259"", ""country_origin"": """", ""udid"": ""c9ddf7806e71c1c6"", ""gender"": """", ""age"": """", ""device"": ""SM-T235Y"", ""session_id"": """", ""push"": ""N"", ""os"": ""4.4.2"", ""browser"": """"}","2015-05-31T22:56:49.000+0800","page_view","",51ee0d904055aa1539d32523,"Apple Daily TW","æœ€æ–°",92,620259,"å°?ç¬ åŽŸç¾¤å³¶å¤–æµ·8.5åœ°éœ‡ã€€ç‚ºä½•æ²’å¼•ç™¼æµ·å˜¯ï¼Ÿ",,"","","",14,31,56,may,49,sunday,2015,local,1433084209738,"SM-T235Y","",,"","Noams-MacBook-Air.local","page_view_raw","192.168.0.11",False,,"",1,"","","å?³æ™‚æ–°è?ž",10002,,"4.4.2",,620259,"å°?ç¬ åŽŸç¾¤å³¶å¤–æµ·8.5åœ°éœ‡ã€€ç‚ºä½•æ²’å¼•ç™¼æµ·å˜¯ï¼Ÿ",Android,"","{"""":_""--_::"",_"""":_"""",_"""":_""__"",_"""":_""..."",_"""":_"""",",N,"","tcp:9898",unknown,"prd-splunk-1.ec2.nxtomopa.internal",,34,"2015-05-31 14:56:49",15,,c9ddf7806e71c1c6,"",,"2.6.0"
```

I also tried putting the article IDs in `articleList` with quotes:

```
articleList = ["600502","600574","600588","600740","600741","601190","601241","601342","601734","601887"]
```

but with no success.

I tried to use this to find out if the row contains any article in the list:

```
if row.any?{ |e| row.include? articleList[e] }
```

still, to no avail.

This seems to be doing the trick:

```
CSV.open('Articles.csv', "wb") do |csv|
    f = File.open('MyFile.csv', "r")
    f.each_line { |line|
        row = line.split(",");
        if row.any? {|e| articleList.include?(e) }
            csv<<row
        end
    }
end
```

Although, I have no idea why.

Comment: Well, show what a `row` looks like.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev done

Comment: I mean, show the parsed one.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev parsed one means?

Comment: @user5346597: `CSV.foreach('MyFile.csv') do |row|` - see row there? That row.

Comment: 1) Are you certain that the CSV is parsed and valid? Try to pp the parsed CSV. 2) Are you certain that the set intersection matches the correct rows? Try PP on both arrays and include the result of `&`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yeah, that's what I put in the example row.

Comment: @berkes I'm sorry, but I am a beginner in Ruby. I don't know what the abbreviation "PP" stands for.

Comment: @user5346597 use `p row`. Right now I can't tell if it's your parsing that is broken or your debug printing.

Comment: @user5346597 pp, stands for [pretty print](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html). an excellent tool to investigate the state of a variable at some point in your code.

Comment: @user5346597 after your last edit: sure this is CSV? It looks an awefully lot like JSON.

Comment: @berkes Yeah. Because I was given this file in the `.csv` extension. And also, in other processing programs I have used this file's data, it seems to work fine.

Comment: That data is a mess.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a different separator. A tab?

If that is the case, you need to [define the col_sep](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new). Separator defaults to a comma, so if you have a Character Separated Values file with a separator other then a Comma, this has to be set.

```
require "pp"
CSV.open("Articles.csv", "wb", col_sep: "\t") do |csv|
  CSV.foreach("MyFile.csv") do |row|
    pp [row & article_list, row]
  end
end
```

Comment: Some additional (potential) improvements: don't mix `""` and `''` quoting. Don't use camelCased variables, CamelCasing is "reserved" for constants in Ruby. but that is OT: just a friendly hint.

Comment: Ok, I tried your code. It seems to put everything in `MyFile.csv` into the new file.